# I want to detect if the DataGridView cell leaves the event only in selecting mode

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to detect the `DataGridViewCell` leave event only in selecting mode not in the editing Mode in C#. That is the code given below is shows here:

```
      private void dgv_CellLeave(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
      {
              if (dgvC.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
              {
                  if (dgv.CurrentCell.Value == null)
                      MessageBox.Show("You have to enter somthing");
              }
      }

    private void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
              if (dgv.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex == 0)
              {
                  if (dgv.CurrentCell.Value.ToString() !="S" )
                      MessageBox.Show("You have to enter S");
              }

 }
```

The above to events work properly when I am selecting the grid cell, but they don't work while editing the cell. Means in both the cases the leave event is occuring. So i wants to detect the current cell is in editing mode or Selecting mode and after that i have to place cursor in the same cell,that should not be changed. Can any one tell me how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hello there try to use this event.

```
    private void dataGridView2_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView2.IsCurrentCellDirty)
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString()))
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Please enter some text before you leave.");
                }
                else if (dataGridView2[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString() != "S")
                {
                    e.Cancel = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("You have to enter S");
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: yeah answers it as he wanted an event that gets triggered when not editing.. but worth noting that for ones that work for when moving away from a cell while editing..  CellEndEdit and CellParsing do

Answer (score 0):

On cell editing mode don't use CurrentCell just use "e" parameter to find a cell.

sample code:

```
private void dgv_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.ColumnIndex == 0)
    {
        if (dgv[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value.ToString() !="S" )
        {
            MessageBox.Show("You have to enter S");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: CellEndEdit like CellParsing, do it for while the cell is being edited, but for when the cell isn't being edited, Cell Validate is the one